# AlwaysOn proc doesn't stop, but it can't be telnet。SqlDumpExceptionHandler: Process {0} g fatal exception c0000094 EXCEPTION_INT_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, crash

I'm a DBA, I'm still learning, and I've recently encountered an Alwayson cluster that can't be used.

Storage failure 1796932693059087230, type 5

```
Event name: SQLException64
Response: Not applicable
Cab ID: 1527799436058424754

Dump:
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * BEGIN STACK DUMP:
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    *   05/25/23 23:33:51 spid 167
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    *
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    *
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    *   Exception Address = 00007FFCCAFC4AFB Module(sqldk+0000000000004AFB)
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    *   Exception Code    = c0000094 EXCEPTION_INT_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    *  
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    *
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    *  MODULE                          BASE      END       SIZE
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * sqlservr                       00007FF7353E0000  00007FF73547CFFF  0009d000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * ntdll                          00007FFCE2EB0000  00007FFCE30AFFFF  00200000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * KERNEL32                       00007FFCE19F0000  00007FFCE1AABFFF  000bc000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * KERNELBASE                     00007FFCE09F0000  00007FFCE0D52FFF  00363000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * ADVAPI32                       00007FFCE1BD0000  00007FFCE1C7DFFF  000ae000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * msvcrt                         00007FFCE14A0000  00007FFCE1542FFF  000a3000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * sechost                        00007FFCE0E00000  00007FFCE0E9EFFF  0009f000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * RPCRT4                         00007FFCE1C80000  00007FFCE1D9DFFF  0011e000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * ole32                          00007FFCE0F40000  00007FFCE1074FFF  00135000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * msvcp_win                      00007FFCE0D60000  00007FFCE0DFFFFF  000a0000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * ucrtbase                       00007FFCE0480000  00007FFCE058FFFF  00110000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * NETAPI32                       00007FFCD1B80000  00007FFCD1B99FFF  0001a000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * GDI32                          00007FFCE1250000  00007FFCE127AFFF  0002b000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * pdh                            00007FFCD2030000  00007FFCD207EFFF  0004f000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * win32u                         00007FFCE08A0000  00007FFCE08C5FFF  00026000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * gdi32full                      00007FFCE08D0000  00007FFCE09E0FFF  00111000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * USER32                         00007FFCE1080000  00007FFCE1224FFF  001a5000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * combase                        00007FFCE1680000  00007FFCE19EFFFF  00370000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * SQLOS                          00007FFCD4E50000  00007FFCD4E58FFF  00009000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * sqldk                          00007FFCCAFC0000  00007FFCCB4E5FFF  00526000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * sqlTsEs                        00007FFCCB5A0000  00007FFCCBE68FFF  008c9000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * OLEAUT32                       00007FFCE1AB0000  00007FFCE1B86FFF  000d7000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * CRYPT32                        00007FFCE0650000  00007FFCE07AEFFF  0015f000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * opends60                       00007FFCD4E40000  00007FFCD4E48FFF  00009000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * qds                            00007FFCCAE90000  00007FFCCAFB8FFF  00129000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * svl                            00007FFCCAE60000  00007FFCCAE8CFFF  0002d000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * MSVCP140                       00007FFCD3C50000  00007FFCD3CEAFFF  0009b000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * MPR                            00007FFCD6010000  00007FFCD602EFFF  0001f000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * VCRUNTIME140                   00007FFCD4750000  00007FFCD4765FFF  00016000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * WINMM                          00007FFCD35B0000  00007FFCD35D6FFF  00027000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * WININET                        00007FFCCA960000  00007FFCCAE5CFFF  004fd000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * sqlmin                         00007FFCCE440000  00007FFCD13F7FFF  02fb8000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * WS2_32                         00007FFCE1420000  00007FFCE1490FFF  00071000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * Secur32                        00007FFCD2020000  00007FFCD202BFFF  0000c000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * WINHTTP                        00007FFCD76E0000  00007FFCD77E8FFF  00109000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * sqllang                        00007FFCCBE70000  00007FFCCE437FFF  025c8000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * ODBC32                         00007FFCCA880000  00007FFCCA939FFF  000ba000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * secforwarder                   00007FFCD2120000  00007FFCD2130FFF  00011000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * NETUTILS                       00007FFCDF7D0000  00007FFCDF7DBFFF  0000c000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * WINTRUST                       00007FFCE07B0000  00007FFCE0819FFF  0006a000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * SSPICLI                        00007FFCDFE40000  00007FFCDFE81FFF  00042000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * DPAPI                          00007FFCE0100000  00007FFCE0109FFF  0000a000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * bcrypt                         00007FFCDFD00000  00007FFCDFD26FFF  00027000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * ncrypt                         00007FFCDFCD0000  00007FFCDFCF7FFF  00028000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * USERENV                        00007FFCDFA60000  00007FFCDFA8DFFF  0002e000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * AUTHZ                          00007FFCDF2A0000  00007FFCDF2ECFFF  0004d000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * XmlLite                        00007FFCDCCC0000  00007FFCDCCF6FFF  00037000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * dhcpcsvc                       00007FFCD83E0000  00007FFCD83FCFFF  0001d000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * SAMCLI                         00007FFCD9640000  00007FFCD9658FFF  00019000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * LOGONCLI                       00007FFCD6E20000  00007FFCD6E61FFF  00042000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * NTASN1                         00007FFCDFC90000  00007FFCDFCC6FFF  00037000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * psapi                          00007FFCE12F0000  00007FFCE12F7FFF  00008000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * MSASN1                         00007FFCDFE20000  00007FFCDFE31FFF  00012000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * kernel.appcore                 00007FFCDEDE0000  00007FFCDEDF6FFF  00017000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * bcryptPrimitives               00007FFCE0820000  00007FFCE089CFFF  0007d000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * instapi150                     00007FFCC7390000  00007FFCC73A3FFF  00014000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * CRYPTSP                        00007FFCDFBC0000  00007FFCDFBD7FFF  00018000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * rsaenh                         00007FFCDF4F0000  00007FFCDF524FFF  00035000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * CRYPTBASE                      00007FFCDFBB0000  00007FFCDFBBBFFF  0000c000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * imagehlp                       00007FFCE1550000  00007FFCE156EFFF  0001f000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * gpapi                          00007FFCDFA00000  00007FFCDFA24FFF  00025000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * wkscli                         00007FFCD7500000  00007FFCD7519FFF  0001a000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * cscapi                         00007FFCC6F50000  00007FFCC6F61FFF  00012000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * sqlevn70                       00000235191E0000  0000023519352FFF  00173000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * sqlevn70                       0000023519370000  00000235196A8FFF  00339000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * CLUSAPI                        00007FFCD2A30000  00007FFCD2B3CFFF  0010d000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * RESUTILS                       00007FFCD2B40000  00007FFCD2BCFFFF  00090000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * VERSION                        00007FFCD3EE0000  00007FFCD3EE9FFF  0000a000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * hkruntime                      00007FFCC4EA0000  00007FFCC5172FFF  002d3000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * hkcompile                      00007FFCC4D60000  00007FFCC4E9FFFF  00140000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * hkengine                       00007FFCC4660000  00007FFCC4D55FFF  006f6000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * dbghelp                        00007FFCD1BA0000  00007FFCD1DB1FFF  00212000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * SHLWAPI                        00007FFCE2E10000  00007FFCE2E6EFFF  0005f000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * ncryptprov                     00007FFCD48C0000  00007FFCD491DFFF  0005e000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * msv1_0                         00007FFCDF8E0000  00007FFCDF96EFFF  0008f000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * NtlmShared                     00007FFCDF8D0000  00007FFCDF8DDFFF  0000e000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * cryptdll                       00007FFCDF9E0000  00007FFCDF9F4FFF  00015000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * kerberos                       00007FFCDFA90000  00007FFCDFBACFFF  0011d000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * schannel                       00007FFCDF400000  00007FFCDF49BFFF  0009c000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * SECURITY                       000002620D1B0000  000002620D1B2FFF  00003000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * MSCOREE                        00007FFCD1400000  00007FFCD1466FFF  00067000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * mscoreei                       00007FFCCB4F0000  00007FFCCB599FFF  000aa000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * SqlServerSpatial150            00007FFCC1170000  00007FFCC1211FFF  000a2000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * clbcatq                        00007FFCE1570000  00007FFCE161EFFF  000af000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * msxml3                         00007FFCC0210000  00007FFCC047BFFF  0026c000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * ualapi                         00007FFCD6050000  00007FFCD6069FFF  0001a000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * SHELL32                        00007FFCE1E90000  00007FFCE25EAFFF  0075b000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * ntmarta                        00007FFCDE960000  00007FFCDE993FFF  00034000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * ESENT                          00007FFCD5A40000  00007FFCD5DD9FFF  0039a000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * msoledbsql                     00007FFCBFF60000  00007FFCC0202FFF  002a3000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * COMDLG32                       00007FFCE28A0000  00007FFCE2982FFF  000e3000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * shcore                         00007FFCE25F0000  00007FFCE26D9FFF  000ea000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * COMCTL32                       00007FFCBF5F0000  00007FFCBF6A1FFF  000b2000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * IPHLPAPI                       00007FFCDF6C0000  00007FFCDF6ECFFF  0002d000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * imm32                          00007FFCE1B90000  00007FFCE1BC0FFF  00031000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * MSOLEDBSQLR                    000002621D340000  000002621D350FFF  00011000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * sqlncli11                      00007FFCBF290000  00007FFCBF5E3FFF  00354000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * MSVCR100                       000000005CB60000  000000005CC31FFF  000d2000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * SQLNCLIR11                     000002621D410000  000002621D437FFF  00028000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * sqlnclirda11                   000000005C800000  000000005CB58FFF  00359000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * SQLNCLIRDAR11                  000002621D530000  000002621D567FFF  00038000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * windows.storage                00007FFCD21E0000  00007FFCD2A27FFF  00848000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * clr                            00007FFCC9AC0000  00007FFCCA5F4FFF  00b35000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * ucrtbase_clr0400               00007FFCC9920000  00007FFCC99DCFFF  000bd000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * VCRUNTIME140_CLR0400           00007FFCC99E0000  00007FFCC99F5FFF  00016000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * mscorlib.ni                    00007FFCC8170000  00007FFCC976FFFF  01600000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * SqlAccess                      00007FFCBF210000  00007FFCBF285FFF  00076000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * BatchParser                    00007FFCBEC70000  00007FFCBEC99FFF  0002a000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * clrjit                         00007FFCC7240000  00007FFCC738EFFF  0014f000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * profapi                        00007FFCE03B0000  00007FFCE03D0FFF  00021000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * SRVCLI                         00007FFCDAFD0000  00007FFCDAFF7FFF  00028000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * mskeyprotect                   00007FFCC2CB0000  00007FFCC2CC4FFF  00015000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * mswsock                        00007FFCDF970000  00007FFCDF9D7FFF  00068000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * ntdsapi                        00007FFCD4F40000  00007FFCD4F69FFF  0002a000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * DSPARSE                        00007FFCD3ED0000  00007FFCD3EDBFFF  0000c000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * ncryptsslp                     00007FFCC4630000  00007FFCC4655FFF  00026000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * xpsqlbot                       00007FFCCA940000  00007FFCCA949FFF  0000a000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * xpstar                         00007FFCBEB00000  00007FFCBEB71FFF  00072000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * SQLSCM                         00007FFCBEC20000  00007FFCBEC33FFF  00014000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * xpstar                         0000026221050000  0000026221058FFF  00009000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * xplog70                        00007FFCBCE90000  00007FFCBCEA5FFF  00016000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * xplog70                        00000262210A0000  00000262210A2FFF  00003000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * sqlvdi                         00007FFCACA80000  00007FFCACABAFFF  0003b000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * SAMLIB                         00007FFCD2C90000  00007FFCD2CB6FFF  00027000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * xprepl                         00007FFCB3EB0000  00007FFCB3ECBFFF  0001c000
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    *
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    *     P1Home: 0000000000000040:  
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    *     P2Home: 0000000001000000:  
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    *     P3Home: 0000000000013855:  
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    *     P4Home: 0000000000000007:  
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    *     P5Home: 00000262275E4CF0:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  000002359997EF98  000002359997EF98  000002445B380000  0000000000000000  
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    *     P6Home: 000002445B3EA000:  0100A00000000101  008200010043E327  002200010043E331  1F37008500000491  000000010043E330  0001F99700004910  
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * ContextFlags: 000000000010005F:  
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    *      MxCsr: 0000000000001FA8:  
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    *      SegCs: 0000000000000033:  
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    *      SegDs: 000000000000002B:  
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    *      SegEs: 000000000000002B:  
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    *      SegFs: 0000000000000053:  
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    *      SegGs: 000000000000002B:  
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    *      SegSs: 000000000000002B:  
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    *     EFlags: 0000000000010206:  
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    *        Rax: 00000000000270AA:  
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    *        Rcx: 0000020528052E9A:  
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    *        Rdx: 0000000000000000:  
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    *        Rbx: 0000000000013855:  
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    *        Rsp: 0000003C073FDC10:  FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF  00007FFCCAFC2CC2  0000003C073FDF70  0000003C073FDF40  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    *        Rbp: 0000003C073FDD10:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    *        Rsi: 0000F8C38978D4B3:  
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    *        Rdi: 0000003C073FDDB0:  FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF  FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF  FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF  FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF  FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF  FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF  
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    *         R8: 00000000000000AF:  
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    *         R9: 0000000000000002:  
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    *        R10: 0000024999580040:  00007FFCCB188ED8  0000024999595FE0  0000024999360050  00000249995A0050  000000000000000F  0000024999034398  
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    *        R11: 0000000000000000:  
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    *        R12: 0000003C073FDFD0:  0000F8C38A1094DF  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  0000000000000028  0000F8C38A1094DF  
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    *        R13: 0000000000000001:  
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    *        R14: 00007FFCCB218C20:  00007FFCCB219998  00007FFCCB2180A0  0000000000000001  00007FFCCB219998  0000000000000003  0000024999031E50  
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    *        R15: 00007FFCCB2173C0:  0000000000000000  0000000000000000  00007FFCCB2199B8  00007FFCCB2166F0  0000000000000006  00007FFCCB2199B8  
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    *        Rip: 00007FFCCAFC4AFB:  3024448948F3F749  000013E882B70F41  2A058D48800C8D48  10C854B70F0025BA  828B4908C87C8B48  48C72348000013F0  
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * *******************************************************************************
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2023-05-25 23:33:51.87 spid167s    * Short Stack Dump
2023-05-25 23:33:51.88 spid167s    00007FFCCAFC4AFB Module(sqldk+0000000000004AFB)
2023-05-25 23:33:51.88 spid167s    00007FFCCAFC46A5 Module(sqldk+00000000000046A5)
2023-05-25 23:33:51.88 spid167s    00007FFCCAFC2E49 Module(sqldk+0000000000002E49)
2023-05-25 23:33:51.88 spid167s    00007FFCCAFC1E37 Module(sqldk+0000000000001E37)
2023-05-25 23:33:51.88 spid167s    00007FFCCAFC221A Module(sqldk+000000000000221A)
2023-05-25 23:33:51.89 spid167s    00007FFCCAFC3C44 Module(sqldk+0000000000003C44)
2023-05-25 23:33:51.89 spid167s    00007FFCCF8AF987 Module(sqlmin+000000000146F987)
2023-05-25 23:33:51.89 spid167s    00007FFCCF8B1BA4 Module(sqlmin+0000000001471BA4)
2023-05-25 23:33:51.89 spid167s    00007FFCCAFC6523 Module(sqldk+0000000000006523)
2023-05-25 23:33:51.89 spid167s    00007FFCCAFC6E6D Module(sqldk+0000000000006E6D)
2023-05-25 23:33:51.89 spid167s    00007FFCCAFC6C75 Module(sqldk+0000000000006C75)
2023-05-25 23:33:51.89 spid167s    00007FFCCAFEB160 Module(sqldk+000000000002B160)
2023-05-25 23:33:51.89 spid167s    00007FFCCAFEAA5B Module(sqldk+000000000002AA5B)
2023-05-25 23:33:51.90 spid167s    00007FFCCAFEAFA4 Module(sqldk+000000000002AFA4)
2023-05-25 23:33:51.90 spid167s    00007FFCE1A04ED0 Module(KERNEL32+0000000000014ED0)
2023-05-25 23:33:51.90 spid167s    00007FFCE2F2E39B Module(ntdll+000000000007E39B)
2023-05-25 23:33:51.96 spid167s    Stack Signature for the dump is 0x000000008E9BFFF3
2023-05-25 23:33:56.41 spid167s    External dump process return code 0x20000001.
External dump process returned no errors.

2023-05-25 23:36:43.41 Server      CImageHelper::Init () Version-specific dbghelp.dll is not used
2023-05-25 23:36:43.44 Server      **Dump thread - spid = 0, EC = 0x0000000000000000
2023-05-25 23:36:43.44 Server      ***Stack Dump being sent to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.BETASQLSERVER\MSSQL\LOG\SQLDump0002.txt
2023-05-25 23:36:43.44 Server      * *******************************************************************************
2023-05-25 23:36:43.44 Server      *
2023-05-25 23:36:43.44 Server      * BEGIN STACK DUMP:
2023-05-25 23:36:43.44 Server      *   05/25/23 23:36:43 spid 3592
2023-05-25 23:36:43.44 Server      *
2023-05-25 23:36:43.44 Server      * Stalled IOCP Listener
2023-05-25 23:36:43.44 Server      *
2023-05-25 23:36:43.44 Server      * *******************************************************************************
2023-05-25 23:36:43.44 Server      * -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
2023-05-25 23:36:43.44 Server      * Short Stack Dump
2023-05-25 23:36:43.44 Server      Stack Signature for the dump is 0x00000000000002E0
```

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using? Run `select @@version` to find out. Add that to the question, don't add a comment. Those are hard to read and ephemeral anyway.

Comment: CONTEXT:  (.ecxr)
rax=00000000000270aa rbx=0000000000013855 rcx=0000020528052e9a
rdx=0000000000000000 rsi=0000f8c38978d4b3 rdi=0000003c073fddb0
rip=00007ffccafc4afb rsp=0000003c073fdc10 rbp=0000003c073fdd10
 r8=00000000000000af  r9=0000000000000002 r10=0000024999580040
r11=0000000000000000 r12=0000003c073fdfd0 r13=0000000000000001
iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na po nc
cs=0033  ss=002b  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00010206
sqldk!SOS_Scheduler::ComputeUtilizationAndDeficit+0x2c1:
00007ffc`cafc4afb 49f7f3          div     rax,r11 -- error

Comment: @vonPryz Thank you for your attention,
Here is version information：
Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM) - 15.0.2000.5 (X64)   Sep 24 2019 13:48:23   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows Server 2019 Datacenter 10.0 <X64> (Build 17763: )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message, `EXCEPTION_INT_DIVIDE_BY_ZERO` suggests there is a bug in the SQL Server's application code. These aren't usually user-fixable, though sometimes there are work-arounds.

Since the version you are using is 15.0.2000.5, you are running the [initial release version](https://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/#sql2019x) of SQL Server 2019. There has been 20 update packages released to SQL Server 2019, and the most recent has been published last April.

The first piece of advice is to install the [latest product update](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/5024276) (some will advice for [latest-1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/5023049), in case the latest has surprising issues, see each update's readme).

While you are at it, install all available Windows updates too. If there are VM tools updates, SAN drivers and whatnot, just get everything up to date. You are going to have an unplanned maintenance break anyway, and trying to save a hour or two is saving from the wrong place.

SQL Server's cumulative update model means that each update will include all the updates in previous packages. Thus, you don't need to install each version but just pick one of the most recent ones.

If you have a support contract with Microsoft, the first thing they tell you is the same - install all the product updates and see if that resovles the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response and advice! It's greatly appreciated. I will make sure to install the latest product update as well as all available Windows updates, VM tools updates, SAN drivers and whatnot to ensure everything is up to date. Your help is truly invaluable!